# Maven "could not resolve dependencies" and "failed to read artifact descriptor" error

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I am using Maven2 eclipse plugin to download dependencies for my project. Although if I compare my repository folder with that of other members in my team using the same Maven repositories and settings.xml, I do not have a lot of jars.

Maven is somehow not able to download them. I copied the settings.xml from a co-worker still it doesnt work for me.

I checked but I am not behind a proxy. One more thing, I am logged into a personal profile in my computer and my repository is a part of the profile. Can this be an issue?

I get the following errors everytime I try building:

```
Failed to execute goal on project ComputerAccess: Could not resolve dependencies for project housing:ComputerAccess:war:2.1.4:
Failed to collect dependencies for [struts:struts:jar:1.2.7 (compile),
org.apache.portals.bridges:portals-bridges-struts:jar:1.2.7-1.0
(compile), org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga (provided),
housing:common:jar:0.6 (compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3
(provided), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile),
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4 (provided),
commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4 (provided),
com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.5 (compile),
org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.1.GA (provided),
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.GA (provided),
org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.1.GA (provided),
commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2 (provided),
javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1 (provided), housing:ufldap:jar:1.0
(compile), commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.0 (provided),
net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3 (provided),
org.jboss.portal.common:common-common:jar:1.2.2 (provided),
c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1 (provided), jboss:jboss-ejb3x:jar:4.2.3.GA
(provided), net.sf.jt400:jt400-full:jar:6.0 (provided),
javax.portlet:portlet-api:jar:1.0 (provided),
housing:housing-login-module:jar:0.8.1 (provided),
javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1 (compile),
org.apache.commons:commons-email:jar:1.1 (compile),
housing:housing-persistence:jar:1.0 (compile),
housing:ComputerAccessPersistence:jar:1.1-dev (compile),
housing:ufdirectory:jar:1.0-dev (compile)]: Failed to read artifact
descriptor for apache-tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.12: Could not transfer
artifact apache-tomcat:catalina:pom:5.5.12 from/to
repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/): Access
denied to
http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/apache-tomcat/catalina/5.5.12/catalina-5.5.12.pom.
Error code 403, Forbidden -    [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
```

The folder "maven2" in the path http://repository.jboss.org/ does not exist, but still it's somehow going to this path; this is not mentioned in my settings.xml too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JBoss changed their Maven 2 repository to https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public.

Update your POM or settings.xml file as appropriate. The other members of your team likely have been around longer than you, thus their local repository is populated with artifacts from before the repository URL changed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to c: -> documents and settings -> users -> .m2 ->repository.
2. Delete all files.
3. In eclipse, rightclick on project.
4. select mave -> update project.
5. check in c: -> documents and settings -> users -> .m2 ->repository. (here jar files will appear).
6. rightclick on project. goto properties -> deploayment assembly -> click add.
7. select java build path entries. click next.
8. select mavendepencies. click finish.

*****--------------It really working----------------*****

Comment: The local repository is not always in `%USERPROFILE%\.m2` since it can be overriden in a `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue resolving some of the dependencies for Jasper Reports. The answer given by [SingleShot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7985839/5990157) above worked to resolve some of the dependencies, but that repository does not include Apache Commons Collections.

I replaced the repository URL with:

- https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/ (from [this answer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/967926/issue-maven-plugin-codehaus-dec-9-2015)), and
- http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/ (from [this answer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/528632/problem-building-jasperreports-300-maven))

This resolved all the dependencies.